# setCenter for Google Map in Angular Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using a directive to create mini maps, given the attributes `lat` and `lng`, repositioning the map automatically if these values change:

```
.directive('map', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      lat: '@',
      lng: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var lat = scope.$eval(attrs.lat);
      var lng = scope.$eval(attrs.lng);

      var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),

      mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        draggable: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        styles: [...],
        disableDefaultUI: true
      },
      map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions),
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map,
        icon: {
          url: 'img/marker.png',
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(24, 32)
        }
      });

      function update() {
        lat = scope.$eval(attrs.lat);
        lng = scope.$eval(attrs.lng);
        center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        map.setCenter(center);
        marker.setPosition(center);

        console.log('updated');
      }

      attrs.$observe('lat', update);
      attrs.$observe('lng', update);
    }
  };
})
```

An example of this in use is:

```
<div class="smallMap" lat="49" lng="-1" map></div>
```

This works fine usually, but there is a problem when using it in a modal. As the directive is fired before the modal is opened, it is not visible in the DOM. Therefore, `setCenter` does not work (see http://www.blogbyben.com/2011/12/gotcha-of-day-google-maps-setcenter.html).

Is there any way to force the directive to fire after the modal has been opened, or another way to solve the issue of centering the map before it is visible in the DOM?

Comment: Did you try to also update on resize events? Then you would just have to figure out where to trigger the resize event and have a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure the map is positioned properly replace the lines in directive:

```
map.setCenter(center);
marker.setPosition(center);
```

with

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
     map.setCenter(center);
     //marker.setPosition(center);
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
});
```

Assuming your map is displayed via [`AngularJS Modal directive`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal) the following example demonstrates how to display Google Maps in modal dialog

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/bpwGjK)

Comment: This will not work because the map will idle before it is visible, so you have the same problem. However, the map tiles do not load until they are visible, so you can use the `tilesloaded` event instead. Update your answer, and I'll mark it as accepted.